# The Hausdorff dimension of the set of reals of inner models

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, hausdorff-dimension

Suppose that both $M$ and $N$ are models of $ZFC$ with $M\subseteq N$ so that $M$ is definable in $N$.

> **Question** Can $(\mathbb{R})^M$ have Hausdorff dimension strictly between $0$ and $1$ in $N$? How about $M=L$?

Note that the question has a negative answer if $N$ is a model of $ZF+DC+AD$.

The motivation of this question is from Erdos and Volkmann's question whether every Borel subring of $\mathbb{R}$ has Hausdorff dimension either $0$ or $1$. Bourgain and, Edgar and Miller, independently gave a positive answer. But it remains open whether *every subfield* of $\mathbb{R}$  has Hausdorff dimension either $0$ or $1$.  This question has a negative answer under $CH$ by Mauldin and Davis.  I think the strongest question along this line is the one I asked. Maudlin-Davies method does not work in this setting.

Comment: Have you tried forcing with the Borel sets modulo the ideal of sets with Hausdorff dimension $< d$ for some $d \in (0,1)$? I don't know enough about Hausdorff dimension to decide whether this should work or not.

Comment: No idea. It would not be simple due to the result of Mauldin-Davies. Also the question seems related to some rather deep results in recursion theory.

Comment: Probably not a viable suggestion then. When I made my comment, I was thinking that you could prove the ground model reals have Hausdorff dimension $\geq d$ in the extension in kind of the same way that you prove they have full outer measure in a random extension. But after thinking about it a bit more yesterday, I doubt it. I'm not even sure this poset would have the ccc, so all sorts of things could go wrong.